# Error when get data from div class using preg_match

Tags: php

```
$data = '
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="photoImg"><img alt="650" src="e43d058fb6424d2dbdc83164146d754f-650.jpg">
    </div>
<div class="eventImg">Event</div>
';
```

And I using function preg_match()

```
preg_match('#<div class="photoImg".*?>(.*?)</div>#', $data, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

=> result null

```
Array
(
)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Add `s` identifier: http://ideone.com/l9zfw6 ; Or better, use DOM to parse XML/like-XML content.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/254973